# (tidy, glance, augment) with exec

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang, broom

I see from the `purrr` documentation that it should be possible to map a list of functions onto arguments using the `map(list(fn1, fn2, fn3), exec, !!!args)` syntax or something similar.  How would this work for the `broom` functions `tidy`, `glance`, and `augment`, which usually must be supplemented with `do`?  These are three functions I almost always like to execute at the same time on the same data and model.  Of course I can do this explicitly:

```
# works but is repetitive
MY_MODEL <- hp ~ cyl
my_glance <- mtcars %>% do(glance(lm(data = ., formula = MY_MODEL)))
my_tidy <- mtcars %>% do(tidy(lm(data = ., formula = MY_MODEL)))
my_augment <- mtcars %>% do(augment(lm(data = ., formula = MY_MODEL)))
```

I suspect there is a better, more compact way to do this without having to retype `...lm(data = ., formula = MY_MODEL...` every time, but I couldn't figure it out.  I tried

```
# doesn't work
omnibroom <- function(df, model){
    map(list(glance, tidy, augment),
        exec,
        ~{(do(.x(lm(data = df, formula = model))))}
        )
    }

omnibroom(mtcars, MY_MODEL)
```

but I think I don't understand the `!!!` syntax appropriately.

*Is there a compact idiom for calling these three broom functions on the same model and data*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this in two lines with simple re-factoring. No `do` or `!!!` necessary.

```
mdl <- mtcars %>% lm(data=., formula=MY_MODEL)
res1 <- map( list(glance, tidy, augment), exec, mdl )
```

If you really want to squish it down into a single line, use `{` to help guide pipe input to the correct place in `lm`:

```
res2 <- mtcars %>% 
    {map( list(glance, tidy, augment), exec, lm(data=., formula=MY_MODEL) )}
```

Verification:

```
identical( res1, list(my_glance, my_tidy, my_augment) )    # TRUE
identical( res1, res2 )                                    # TRUE
```

**EDIT to address grouping**

Arbitrary functions like `lm` don't respect data frame groups. While `do` is a popular approach to handle grouping in this case, I personally think that `tidyr::nest()` is more intuitive because it places all intermediates and results alongside the data:

```
## "Listify" broom functions: f -> map( ..., f )
omnibroom <- map( list(glance, tidy, augment), ~function(l) map(l, .x) ) %>%
    set_names( c("glance","tidy","augment") )

result <- mtcars %>% nest( data = -gear ) %>%
    mutate( model = map(data, lm, formula=MY_MODEL) ) %>%
    mutate_at( "model", omnibroom )

#  # A tibble: 3 x 6
#     gear data              model  glance           tidy           augment
#    <dbl> <list>            <list> <list>           <list>         <list>
#  1     4 <tibble [12 × 10… <lm>   <tibble [1 × 11… <tibble [2 × … <tibble [12 × …
#  2     3 <tibble [15 × 10… <lm>   <tibble [1 × 11… <tibble [2 × … <tibble [15 × …
#  3     5 <tibble [5 × 10]> <lm>   <tibble [1 × 11… <tibble [2 × … <tibble [5 × 9…
```

This format also naturally lends itself to unnesting, since `broom` functions produce data frames:

```
result %>% select( gear, tidy ) %>% unnest( tidy )

#  # A tibble: 6 x 6
#     gear term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1     4 (Intercept)    -5.00     25.3     -0.198 0.847
#  2     4 cyl            20.2       5.30     3.82  0.00339
#  3     3 (Intercept)   -47.5      56.1     -0.847 0.412
#  4     3 cyl            30.0       7.42     4.04  0.00142
#  5     5 (Intercept)  -101.       51.9     -1.94  0.148
#  6     5 cyl            49.4       8.28     5.96  0.00944
```

Comment: Wow, way simpler than I thought.  Thank you for this.

Comment: Just realized this solution doesn't respect the groupings of the dataframe, which is one of the main reasons to use broom.  i.e. these give the same output: `out <- mtcars %>%  {map( list(glance, tidy), exec, lm(data=., formula=MY_FORMULA) )};
out2 <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% {map( list(glance, tidy), exec, lm(data=., formula=MY_FORMULA) )}`

Comment: Hi @CurtF. Please see my edit to address the grouping question.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for the edit.  I'd upvote and accept a 2nd time if I could...